# Qt display non-uniform hierarchy

Tags: c++, qt

The following is the logical hierarchy of data that I want to display.

```
root
|
+ node_name0 ---- collection<A> ---- collection<B>
|                 |                  |
|                 + item<A>[0]       + item<B>[0]
|                 |                  |
|                 + item<A>[1]       + item<B>[1]
|                 |
|                 + item<A>[2]
|
+ node_name1 ---- [...]
|
[...]
```

As far as I can tell, Qt's table view will not be able to display this data without a massive loss in fidelity. Nor will its list view. Qt's tree view could display the data if I reshaped the hierarchy to look like this:

```
root
|
+ node_name
| |
| + collection<A>
| | |
| | + item<A>[0]
| | |
| | [...]
| |
| [...]
|
[...]
```

But that, in my opinion, escapes from the fact that the items of `collection<A>` and the items of `collection<B>` have entirely different semantics.

I already have an implementation of `QAbstractItemModel` that provides the data arrangement given in the first bit of ASCII art.

How do I display this data?

What Qt support libraries are out there that could provide views that would make my life easier?

**Wishlist**

- I don't want to use a hierarchy of multiple views with proxy models (but I'll bite the bullet if need be).
- I don't want to pay for anything (because I could just bite the bullet and use multiple views and proxy models).
- It'd be excellent if whatever solution is given could handle a deeper hierarchy, i.e. display the subdata of `item<A>[*]` and `item<B>[*]`.

Comment: I dont get your point quite honestly. If you want to use the treeview, simply derive treeviewitem and add a pointer to your base class ( item<A> and item<b> share one right? ) and cast down to your specific pointer if required. But all a treeview does is display _text_. So you can handle what kind of text is added in what way when you register your item to the treeview?

Comment: @Najzero ... I don't want to use the tree view. The items of both collections are semantically distinct, and therefore ought to be displayed as semantically distinct (ex. like having a table of keys, two tables of key -> value, and joining over keys in a SQL DB), hence why I'm leaning heavily toward just separating the hierarchy out into a hierarchy of proxy models. That was written out specifically to dissuade people from wasting their time by suggesting that I reshape to a treeview (which is the most trivial solution).

That said, I could scarcely understand your last sentence.

Comment: Then don't try to display everything in one view. How about using separate treeviews (or tableviews) for separate collections? Or the treeview displays only one collection at a time and you have some other widget (combobox, listview, ...) which is used to select which collection is viewed. You should consider how the user uses the information and does the user really need to see all existing information or maybe a smaller (more easily presented) subset is enough.

Comment: @Roku The only thing keeping me from doing that as a final solution is that I'm hoping someone else has already written a library for this somewhere that I haven't found yet, and that StackOverflow has in its experience found solutions in the deep dark recesses of the internet that I haven't touched yet despite my constant scouring.

Comment: I'm sure some kind of custom view widget could be made for that data structure. But the problem with complicated nonstandard widgets is the user. The users do not know how to use the custom widget and most users don't like that. Sure, users will learn how to use custom widget, if they use it long enough. But if your program is used only occasionally, that learning can take a very long time. That's why using standard widgets is quite often the better alternative, even if the custom widget would be a little more efficient in the hands of experienced user.

Comment: @Roku That is a totally valid point. If you want to put that reasoning into an answer, I'm perfectly willing to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to display everything in one view. How about using separate treeviews (or tableviews) for separate collections? Or the treeview displays only one collection at a time and you have some other widget (combobox, listview, ...) which is used to select which collection is viewed.

You should consider how the user uses the information and does the user really need to see all existing information or maybe a smaller (more easily presented) subset is enough.

I'm sure some kind of custom view widget could be made for that data structure. But the problem with complicated nonstandard widgets is the user. The users do not know how to use the custom widget and most users don't like that. Sure, users will learn how to use custom widgets, if they use it long enough. But if your program is used only occasionally, that learning can take a very long time. That's why using standard widgets is quite often the better alternative, even if the custom widget would be a little more efficient in the hands of experienced user.